# firebase callable function won't invoke

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

My project is using vue framework. I have been using the firebase service for a while and everything works properly (firestore, real time db etc.) triggered cloud functions also works properly. oncall functions also used to work properly for a long time.
The problem is that suddenly all of the callable functions stopped working. I send firebase a call for some callable function to invoke, and then the code brakes and the console shows a weird error as shown below. Firebase functions logs do not show any log, which means that the function hasn't even started.

here is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Notification' in undefined
at ContextProvider.eval (index.esm.js?10fa:207)
at step (tslib.es6.js?40cb:102)
at Object.eval [as next] (tslib.es6.js?40cb:83)
at eval (tslib.es6.js?40cb:76)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js?40cb:72)
at ContextProvider.getInstanceIdToken (index.esm.js?10fa:204)
at ContextProvider.eval (index.esm.js?10fa:232)
at step (tslib.es6.js?40cb:102)
at Object.eval [as next] (tslib.es6.js?40cb:83)
```

the " 'in' operator to search for 'Notification' in undefined" is firebase code within the node modules

**edit:**

the local function calling the cloud function:

```
 async send(index) {
...
 await serv_inviteMatch({invitation, myId:myUser.answers.id, 
 matchId:this.user.answers.id})
}
```

firebase/functions.js:

```
import Firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/functions';
... 
export const serv_inviteMatch = Firebase.functions().httpsCallable('inviteMatch');
```

functions/index.js:

```
exports.inviteMatch = functions.https.onCall(async (invitationData) =>{...})
```

Comment: can you share more of that you have written to call this function? also use @ my username to notify otherwise we will not be able to see your comment reply

Comment: @Abhishek thank you, i added some code in the question. is it clearer now?

Comment: hey looks like you just need to follow firebase tutorial on writing async functions, terminating them can be tricky. They need proper promise clause. watch the video I gave in the answers, it will help you understand the functions

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific way using which a cloud function should be built to handle errors and promises, for example, there is no need to make the cloud function async. I think you will need to watch the [tutorial series from Firebase team](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM) that will help you understand how each type of firebase function is made and how to write them.

Your cloud function seems to be async here, so you will need to [terminate it properly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) as told by Firebase:

> resolve functions that perform asynchronous processing (also known as "background functions") by returning a JavaScript promise.

Comment: thank you @abhishek, the functions as i created them were working fine the other day. i dont think anithing needs to be changeg in the code. doesnt it look more like a package version thing?

Comment: @chaimthee did you make changes from yesterday? it can be that one of the changes in code or in packages might have caused the error, firebase functions doesn't get compiled locally, that means, the server compiles them, so that narrows down the error to client side code